# The socket server on ubuntu can't be connected

Tags: python, sockets

the code of socket-server and the code of socket-client can run perfectly on my localhost, but when I run the code of socket-server on Ubuntu server, the code of socket-client on my localhost can't connect to Ubuntu server.And the code of socket-client on Ubuntu Server can't connect to my localhost Server.

socket-server.py

```
import socket
import threading

def bbs(conn):
    user_list.append(conn)
    try:
        while 1:
            msg = conn.recv(1024)
            if msg:
                for user in user_list:
                    user.send(msg)
    except ConnectionResetError:
        user_list.remove(conn)
        conn.close()

user_list = []
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('0.0.0.0', 18000))
server.listen()
while 1:
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    t = threading.Thread(target=bbs, args=(conn,))
    t.start()
```

socket-client.py

```
import socket
import threading
import time


def send_msg():
    while 1:
        msg = input()
        client.send((name + '：' + msg).encode('utf-8'))


def recv_msg():
    while 1:
        msg = client.recv(1024)
        if msg:
            try:
                print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
                time.sleep(1)
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                pass

name = input('请输入你的昵称：')
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('10.26.8.132', 18000))
sendmsg_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_msg)
recvmsg_thread = threading.Thread(target=recv_msg)
sendmsg_thread.start()
recvmsg_thread.start()
```

Server is always wait for connection, Client report an error:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] The connection attempt failed because the connecting party did not respond correctly after a period of time or because the connecting host did not respond.
```

Comment: problem solved.The port on the terminal has been opened, but i haven't opened it on my server web console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wang if this works without issue on your localhost, but not over a network connection, it might be a firewall issue on both client & server. You can use 'nc' (netcat) for testing the connection from client to the server.